# How to serialize Map<String, List<Integer>> using gson?

Tags: json, collections, hashmap, gson

I'm getting trouble with gson.
When I call toJson() method it throws StackOverflowError whatever I do.

Here's snippet I'm trying.

```
private Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> mMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>() {{
    put("KEY_A", new ArrayList<Integer>( Arrays.asList(1,2,3)));
    put("KEY_B", new ArrayList<Integer>( Arrays.asList(1,3,5)));
    put("KEY_C", new ArrayList<Integer>( Arrays.asList(1,2,3)));
}};
Gson gson = new Gson();
public String getString() {
    return gson.toJson(mMap);
}
```

I have tried to put type argument when calling toJson() method like:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
public String getString() {
    return gson.toJson(mMap, type);
}
```

and tried different configuration of type like:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>>>(){}.getType();
// Object -> ArrayList<Integer>
```

but didn't work at all.

Any comment would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable complex map key serialization using `GsonBuilder` object. Here is a working example:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> mMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>() {
    {
        put("KEY_A", new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
        put("KEY_B", new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5)));
        put("KEY_C", new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
    }
};
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization().setPrettyPrinting().create();
Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>>(){}.getType();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(mMap, type));
```

It prints the output:

```
{
  "KEY_A": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "KEY_C": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "KEY_B": [
    1,
    3,
    5
  ]
}
```